# Column 'ID' is constrained to be unique. Value is already present

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, select

I get a constraint error I do not understand.

```
System.Data.ConstraintException: Column 'ID' is constrained to be unique. 
Value '01d3eb89-f4e1-4782-9519-da8f08e0638f' is already present.
```

The value is repeated in Member Data - I do not see how it is constrained to be unique.

The query is

```html
SELECT MemberData.UserId, MemberData.FormRow, MemberData.Value
FROM AuthUsers, MemberData 
WHERE (AuthUsers.GroupId = @groupId AND AuthUsers.Id = MemberData.UserId 
    AND MemberData.FormId = @formId) 
Group By MemberData.UserId, MemberData.FormRow, MemberData.Value
```

`AuthUsers` is the ASP.NET user table with a `groupId` field added which is a Guid.

`MemberData` is the data for form data. It has 
`FormRow (Guid)` - points to the form definition row in FormRow
Value (string)
`Id (int)` - unique auto-increment key
`UserId (string)` - userId from AuthUser table
`FormId (Guid)` - points to the form definition in Forms

MemberData has
`MemberData.UserId` is repeated for each `formRow`, the user's form data collection.
`MemberData.FormRow` has many is repeated for every different `UserId`, each user's data for that `formRow` in `FormId's` form.
`MemberData.FormId` is repeated for every `FormRow` in the Form.
`MemberData.Value` is an arbitrary user entered value.

The error is a user id that repeated 5 times in the data for the five fields it is in.

I am trying to populate member grid summary getting all the data rows in `MemberData` grouped by `UserId` which is the summary row.  The `GroupId` is used because the summary is for all users in the group.

Comment: If change it to
SELECT UserId, FormRow, Value FROM  MemberData WHERE  FormId = @formId
I get the very same error. Works in a query window but not in asp.net code.

Comment: Here is the create table form the table view:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MemberData] (
    [FormRow] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [Value]   NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [Id]      INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId]  NVARCHAR (128)   NULL,
    [FormId]  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.MemberData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.MemberData_dbo.Forms_FormRow] FOREIGN KEY ([FormRow]) REFERENCES [dbo].[FormRow] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

Comment: The really confusing part is that the unique value given in the error is a userid which is just a string in table.  Id is confusing since all the tables have one including the foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

This a little embarrassing,  the message was from grid being loaded not the database.  Pretty confusing, I was fixing some SQL query problems with very similar messages and the final error message looked just like the others in a database consistent way. Problems was fixed in code logic.